# Java: how to set java path for Windows and MAC

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml

I have Java maven project with TestNG

Please see this `pom.xml`:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javac.exe</executable>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So inside `Windows` when I want to run this project from command line I just navigate into this `pom.xml` folder and then:

```
mvn clean test
```

And this will start all my tests.

Now inside this `pom.xml` i have my `javac.exe` path so in order to run this project in `MAC` what I need to add/ change? (I want it to support both OS)

Comment: You could use [maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), trigger the appropriate one based on the environment.

Comment: Can i have simple example ?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would probably be to rely on the standard `JAVA_HOME` environment variable:

```
<executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/java</executable>
```

Comment: Just replace this executable tag with yours ? this will work on both win and mac ?

Comment: But where this env.JAVA_HOME define ?

Comment: This env.JAVA_HOME not recognized